# Qt widget update later but when?

Tags: qt, qt4, signals-slots, qwidget

I'd like to know what happens exactly when I call a QWidget's update() method.
Here is the documentation:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/qwidget.html#update

> This function does not cause an
>   immediate repaint; instead **it
>   schedules a paint event** for processing
>   when Qt returns to the main event
>   loop. This permits Qt to optimize for
>   more speed and less flicker than a
>   call to repaint() does.

I see from the Qt source code that a QUpdateLaterEvent is created and post with type **QEvent::UpdateLater**

In this part of the documentation 
http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/qevent.html

> QEvent::UpdateLater: The widget
>   should be queued to be repainted at a
>   later time.

What does 'later time' mean?
Are my all emited queued signals and the events in the event queue processed before the paint?

Thanks,
Gabor

Comment: You may use "QWidget::repaint()" method to be ensured that your widget will be repainted. Or this is not option for you ?

Comment: No, this is not an option. I emit queued signals in another thread that results widget updates. I emit more than one such signals after each other and I want to be sure that the queued signals are processed before the update and don't update several times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After checking QWidget::update() source code I've found it calls this method in `src/gui/kernel/qwidget.cpp:9544` :

```
void QWidget::update(const QRect &rect)
{
    if (!isVisible() || !updatesEnabled() || rect.isEmpty())
        return;

    if (testAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_InPaintEvent)) {
        QApplication::postEvent(this, new QUpdateLaterEvent(rect));
        return;
    }

    if (hasBackingStoreSupport()) {
        QTLWExtra *tlwExtra = window()->d_func()->maybeTopData();
        if (tlwExtra && !tlwExtra->inTopLevelResize && tlwExtra->backingStore)
            tlwExtra->backingStore->markDirty(rect, this);
    } else {
        d_func()->repaint_sys(rect);
    }
}
```

As you can see the `QUpdateLaterEvent` is only posted if the update() is already called from inside a paintEvent() method.

You can also check `QWidget::repaint(const QRect &rect)` source on line 9456 - it lacks `testAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_InPaintEvent)` check.

**EDIT**

The `QUpdateLaterEvent` is posted as a `Qt::NormalEventPriority` event, so it gets processed after all other normal priority events (see `src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp:971` and `:1003`). You might also want to look into compressEvent code, I haven't checked that.

So to finally answer the question: the QUpdateLaterEvent is processed after other high and normal priority events that were in queue before it was posted.

Comment: Thanks, but I have seen this function before. But I'd like to know what happens with the posted event. What is the priority of the event? What other events are processed before/after this event.

Comment: What about the queued signals that were emited in another thread to the main thread? Are the signals processed before the events?

Comment: Documentation is a bit ambiguous on this: couldn't quite make it out if the signals are queued on the sender's or the receiver's event loop.

Comment: The painting is on the main thread and I emit non blocking queued signals from another thread to the main thread. So it is queued on the receiver's thread I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Behavior is not documented == not guaranteed to stay the same between Qt versions.  You shouldn't write code which depends on the ordering of paint events relative to other events.